# How to two way bind to a UserControl DependencyProperty?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I am making a custom slider called `scalar_slider` using a `UserControl`. I would like to two way bind one of it's `DependencyProperty`.

The problem is that the value changes made inside `scalar_slider` are not updated back to the parent's view model `vm` which correctly implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I assume the problem has to do with how I am setting the binding in `MainPage.xaml`.

// MainPage.xaml

```
 <local:scalar_slider scalar_value="{x:Bind vm.my_scalar_value Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

// scalar_slider.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="transformations.scalar_slider"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:transformations"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"> 
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind scalar_value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Slider Value="{x:Bind scalar_value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

//scalar_slider.idl

```
namespace transformations
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass scalar_slider : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl, Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        scalar_slider();    
        static Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty scalar_valueProperty;
        Single scalar_value;
    }
}
```

//scalar_slider.h

```
namespace winrt::transformations::implementation
{
    struct scalar_slider : scalar_sliderT<scalar_slider>
    {
        scalar_slider();

        static Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty scalar_valueProperty();
        static void scalar_valueProperty(Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty value);

        float scalar_value();
        void scalar_value(float value);

        winrt::event_token PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler);
        void PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept;

        template <class T>
        void update_value(hstring const& property_name, T & var, T value)
        {
            if (var != value)
            {
                var = value;
                raise_property_changed(property_name);
            }
        }

    private:
        event<Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler> m_property_changed;
        void raise_property_changed(hstring const& property_name)
        {
            m_property_changed(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs(property_name));
        }

        static Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty m_scalar_value_property;

        float m_scalar_value = 0.0f;
    };
}
```

//scalar_slider.cpp

```
namespace winrt::transformations::implementation
{
    scalar_slider::scalar_slider()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    winrt::event_token scalar_slider::PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler)
    {
        return m_property_changed.add(handler);
    }

    void scalar_slider::PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept
    {
        m_property_changed.remove(token);
    }

    Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty scalar_slider::m_scalar_value_property = Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty::Register(
        L"scalar_value",
        winrt::xaml_typename<float>(),
        winrt::xaml_typename<winrt::transformations::scalar_slider>(),
        Windows::UI::Xaml::PropertyMetadata{ nullptr }
    );

    Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty scalar_slider::scalar_valueProperty()
    {
        return m_scalar_value_property;
    }

    void scalar_slider::scalar_valueProperty(Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty value)
    {
        m_scalar_value_property = value;
    }

    float scalar_slider::scalar_value()
    {
        return m_scalar_value;
    }

    void scalar_slider::scalar_value(float value)
    {
        update_value(L"scalar_value", m_scalar_value, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition for `vm` (particularly its `my_scalar_value` property)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your code, I find the get and set function of `scalar_slider` property you write are not correct in scalar_slider.cpp, you can change them like below code.

You can also read [XAML custom (templated) controls with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/xaml-cust-ctrl) to understand better.

```
float scalar_slider::scalar_value()
{​
    return winrt::unbox_value<float>(GetValue(m_scalar_value_property));​
}​
​
void scalar_slider::scalar_value(float value)​
{​
    SetValue(m_scalar_value_property, winrt::box_value(value));​
    m_property_changed(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs(L"scalar_value"));​
}
```

Comment: From the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/xaml-cust-ctrl) you provided: *"If you want a DP with a floating-point type, then make it `double` (`Double` in MIDL 3.0). Declaring and implementing a DP of type `float` (`Single` in MIDL), and then setting a value for that DP in XAML markup, results in the error **Failed to create a 'Windows.Foundation.Single' from the text ''**."*

Comment: I am using a float right now and it seems to work fine. Maybe this is outdated? I didn't notice any errors.